# Travis test Angularjs Directive: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$compile(...)')

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, travis-ci

I'm trying to add Continuous Integration to an AngularJS Project, but some of the directives test fail. These test do just fine locally. The error code below is similar to all the errors I get.

**the error code**

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) myHead directive compiles a my-head attribute FAILED
    ....
    TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$compile('<div my-head></div>')') in /home/travis/build/../../test/unit/myHeadDirective.js (line 15)
    ....
```

It seem that the injection of the $compile function does not work, while the injection is included in the testing.

**Test code**

```
describe('myHead directive', function () {
  var $compile, $rootScope

  beforeEach(module('myApp.templates'))
  beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'))

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_
  }))

  it('compiles a my-head attribute', function () {
    var compiledElement = $compile('<div my-head></div>')($rootScope)
    $rootScope.$digest()  // Fire watchers
    expect(compiledElement.html()).toContain('tg_page_head')
  })

  it('compiles a my-head element', function () {
    var compiledElement = $compile('<my-head></my-head>')($rootScope)
    $rootScope.$digest()  // Fire watchers
    expect(compiledElement.html()).toContain('tg_page_head')
  })
})
```

I'm new to using Travis, so the Travis settings settings might be the problem. (some of the non-relevant parts are removed)

```
#.travis.yml

language: node_js
sudo: false
node_js:
  - '6'

cache:
  yarn: true

env:
  global:
    - CXX=g++-4.8  # node 4 likes the G++ v4.8 compiler

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8
  code_climate:
    repo_token: '......'


before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp
  - npm install -g

script:
  - gulp build
  - gulp test
```

So, does anyone know *why the $compile function is not defined?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved! It turns out that templates.js needs to be generated before the test are run. I got the $compile function to work by adding the generate script to the before_script of .travis.yml.

so, this is the new before_script:

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp
  - npm install -g
  - gulp templates

script:
  - gulp test
  - gulp build
```